# Aeson does not decode strings with unicode characters

Tags: haskell, unicode, aeson

I'm trying to use Data.Aeson (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.6.1.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html) to decode some JSON strings, however it is failing to parse strings that contain non-standard characters.

As an example, the file:

```
import Data.Aeson
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 (pack)

test1 :: Maybe Value
test1 = decode $ pack "{ \"foo\": \"bar\"}"

test2 :: Maybe Value
test2 = decode $ pack "{ \"foo\": \"bòz\"}"
```

When run in ghci, gives the following results:

```
*Main> :l ~/test.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /Users/ltomlin/test.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> test1
Just (Object fromList [("foo",String "bar")])
*Main> test2
Nothing
```

Is there a reason that it doesn't parse the String with the unicode character? I was under the impression that Haskell was pretty good with unicode. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

tetigi

### EDIT

Upon further investigation using `eitherDecode`, I get the following error message:

```
 *Main> test2
 Left "Failed reading: Cannot decode byte '\\x61': Data.Text.Encoding.decodeUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream"
```

`x61` is the unicode character for 'z', which comes right after the special unicode character. Not sure why it's failing to read the characters after the special character!

Changing `test2` to be `test2 = decode $ pack "{ \"foo\": \"bòz\"}"` instead gives the error:

```
Left "Failed reading: Cannot decode byte '\\xf2': Data.Text.Encoding.decodeUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream"
```

Which is the character for "ò", which makes a bit more sense.

Comment: Do you really use aeson-0.6.1.0? That being said, this seems like some bad encoding between `Text` and `ByteString`. Have you tried to encode the text with `encodeUtf8 :: Text -> ByteString` (from `Data.Text.Encoding`) instead?

Comment: @Zeta I just linked the tab I had open at the time - the Installed version is 0.7.0.4. I'll give it a shot!

Comment: @Zeta That worked! I now get `Right (Object fromList [("foo",String "b\242r")])` :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is your usage of pack from the Char8 module, which doesn't work with non-Latin 1 data. Instead, use [`encodeUtf8`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-2.1/docs/Data-Text-Lazy-Encoding.html#v:encodeUtf8) from text.

You can write your examples like this:

```
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Text.Lazy (pack)
import Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding (encodeUtf8)

test1 :: Maybe Value
test1 = decode $ encodeUtf8 $ pack "{ \"foo\": \"bar\"}"

test2 :: Maybe Value
test2 = decode $ encodeUtf8 $ pack "{ \"foo\": \"bòz\"}"
```

Comment: Oops, looks like Zeta already gave that answer. If he/she rewrites that comment as an answer, please accept that one instead.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman: Nah. This question has a valid/accepted answer now, so there's no need for duplication :D. However, I would include a link to `encodeUtf8`.