# How can I use Aeson to decode JSON files with Unicode characters?

Tags: json, parsing, haskell, utf-8, aeson

(Apologies if I should say UTF8 instead of Unicode.)

I've already come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669418/aeson-does-not-decode-strings-with-unicode-characters), but couldn't make reason out of it after several minutes.

The starting point of that and my question is the following

```hs
import Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.Text.Encoding as E (encodeUtf8)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as C8 (pack)
import qualified Data.Text as T (pack)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print (foo "{ \"foo\": \"bar\"}" :: Maybe Value)
  print (foo "{ \"foo\": \"bòz\"}" :: Maybe Value)
  where
    foo = decode . C8.pack
```

will print

```hs
Just (Object (fromList [("foo",String "bar")]))
Nothing
```

The answer and the comments allude to the solution making use of `encodeUtf8` from `Data.Text.Encoding`. But how?

- `C8.pack` is `String -> ByteString`,
- `E.encodeUtf8` is `Text -> ByteString`,
- `"{ \"foo\": \"bòz\"}"` is `String`,

so I think that if I want to use `E.encodeUtf8`, I need to drop `C8.pack` for a function of type `String -> Text`, and `T.pack` seems to be such a function. However, the following,

```hs
import Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.Text.Encoding as E (encodeUtf8)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as C8 (pack)
import qualified Data.Text as T (pack)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print (foo "{ \"foo\": \"bar\"}" :: Maybe Value)
  print (foo "{ \"foo\": \"bòz\"}" :: Maybe Value)
  where
    foo = decode . E.encodeUtf8 . T.pack
```

fails to compile, with error

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘bytestring-0.11.5.3:Data.ByteString.Internal.Type.ByteString’
                     with ‘Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString’
      Expected: Data.Text.Internal.Text
                -> Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString
        Actual: Data.Text.Internal.Text
                -> bytestring-0.11.5.3:Data.ByteString.Internal.Type.ByteString
      NB: ‘Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString’
            is defined in ‘Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal’
          ‘bytestring-0.11.5.3:Data.ByteString.Internal.Type.ByteString’
            is defined in ‘Data.ByteString.Internal.Type’
    • In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘E.encodeUtf8’
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘E.encodeUtf8 . T.pack’
      In the expression: decode . E.encodeUtf8 . T.pack
   |
11 |     foo = decode . E.encodeUtf8 . T.pack
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: As an aside, I am concerned; all these conversions between string types looks unwieldy. Presumably in your real application you are not starting from a string literal embedded in your program text, but rather from a network transaction or file system access. In either case, you *should* be able to use library functions that produce appropriately-typed `ByteString`s directly, without conversion. If you can't figure out how, or you are starting from something other than the network or a file, it may be worth opening another question with some details.

Comment: @DanielWagner, yes, the strings are from an actual JSON file, and eventually stored in a `data Foo = Foo !String ![String]`. I see what concerns you (the conversions) but _why_ does it concern you and should concern me? What can go wrong, practically? I've just tried putting some unicode characters (emojis like ⌚️) in the JSON file, and the `String` seem to contain the correct value, in the sense that executing `putStrlLn` on those `String`s will correctly print those emojis. I guess this just means that whatever byte I'm putting in, I simply get the same byte out.

Comment: @DanielWagner, maybe you're alluding to cases where I would actually manipulate text, and some multi-byte characters would not behave well with functions like `head`/`tail` and so on?

Comment: Well, besides conversions being a possible source of bugs, it's also just unnecessary work. Why convert from bytes to `String` and back to bytes when you can do neither thing, thus reducing the code you need to write, the memory usage, the computation time, and possibly the size of your library dependency tree? (`String` in particular is a notorious memory hog -- it can be up to 24x as large as the corresponding `ByteString`, and usually with much worse cache locality to boot.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is saying tha `encodeUtf8` produces a strict bytestring while `decode` expects a lazy bytestring. You can probably fix it by using the lazy version, for example by changing the imports:

```
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding as E (encodeUtf8)
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as T (pack)
```